# Convert Integer to Enum in property getter/setter

Tags: delphi, casting, enums, delphi-xe5

I currently have an option management which works with properties, that use all the same getter/setter method but with an index.

This works fine for Ints and Bools, but I'd like to get this working for enums, too.

```
TIntegerOptions = (kInt1, kInt2, kInt3);

class property Integer1: Integer index kInt1 read GetOptionsValueInt write SetOptionsValueInt;
class property Integer2: Integer index kInt2 read GetOptionsValueInt write SetOptionsValueInt;
class property Integer3: Integer index kInt3 read GetOptionsValueInt write SetOptionsWertInt;

FOptionsListInt: array[TIntegerOptions] of IniIntObject;  // Objects contain Inifile read&save functionalities
...

class function GetOptionsValueInt(const aOption: TIntegerOptions) : Integer
begin
  Result := Ord(FOptionsListInt[aOption].GetValue());
end;

class procedure SetOptionsValueInt(const aOption: TIntegerOptions; const aValue: Integer);
begin
  FOptionslistInt[aOption].ChangeTo(aValue);
end;
```

This is working so far, and now my problem:

```
TEnumOptions = (kEnum1, kEnum2, kEnum3);
TEnum1 = (e1o1, e1o2, e1o3);
TEnum2 = (e2o1, e2o2, e2o3);
TEnum3 = (e3o1, e3o2, e3o3);

// these props fail because my functions return / excpect Integers, not the matching Enums
class property Enum1: TEnum1 index kEnum1 read GetOptionsValueInt write SetOptionsValueEnum; 
class property Enum2: TEnum2 index kEnum2 read GetOptionsValueInt write SetOptionsValueEnum;
class property Enum3: TEnum3 index kEnum3 read GetOptionsValueInt write SetOptionsValueEnum;

FOptionsListEnum: array[TEnumOptions] of IniIntObject; // Objects contain Inifile read&save functionalities
```

I marked the problems in the code. Can I somehow cast the Integer values returned by the getters/setters to the matching enum for each property?

For those who read the old question:
I decided to just use the same getter/setter for the enums, cause in the end they get saved as Integers, too. If I need to cast inside the getters somehow, I'll add them again, but i hoped for a solution inside the property-declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your update, you want to use code like this:

```
class property Enum1: TEnum1 index kEnum1 read GetOptionsValueInt;
```

That fails to compile because `GetOptionsValueInt` returns a value of type `Integer`. Since the property has type `TEnum1`, that is a simple type mismatch. In order to have a property of type `TEnum1`, the getter must be a function that returns a value of type `TEnum1`.

If each of these properties has a different type, then you cannot share getter and setter. Shared indexed getters and setters can only be used for properties that share a common type. Since it looks like none of these properties share a type, you will not be able to share getters and setters.

---

**Original answer to original question**

You don't show all the declarations, so it's hard for us to know why your code does not compile. We don't know what `FOptionsListeEnum` is, and we don't know what `Wert()` is.

However, here's a complete program that demonstrates that enumerated types can be used as indexes for indexed properties:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TMyEnum = (evOne, evTwo);

  TMyClass = class
  private
    class function GetValue(const Option: TMyEnum): Integer; static;
  public
    class property ValueOne: Integer index evOne read GetValue;
    class property ValueTwo: Integer index evTwo read GetValue;
  end;

class function TMyClass.GetValue(const Option: TMyEnum): Integer;
begin
  Result := ord(Option);
end;

begin
  Writeln(TMyClass.ValueOne);
  Writeln(TMyClass.ValueTwo);
end.
```

So, that makes it clear that there's no issue using enumerated types as indices. In which case, what is your problem. Let's look at the code you have:

```
class function TKmpOption.GetOptionsWertEnum(const aOption: TEnumOptionen): Integer;
begin
  Result := Ord(FOptionsListeEnum[aOption].Wert());
end;

class procedure TKmpOption.SetOptionsWertEnum(const aOption: TEnumOptionen; const aWert: Integer);
begin
  FOptionslisteEnum[aOption].Aendern(aOption(aWert));
end;
```

If `Ord(FOptionsListeEnum[aOption].Wert())` does not compile with a type mismatch error, then it would seem that `Wert()` is not an ordinal value.

As for `aOption(aWert)` that makes no sense at all. That can never compile. Perhaps you meant `TEnumOptionen(aWert)` but that also makes no sense. Why would the value be of the same type used to index the possible options.

I hope that the code above shows that the issue is not related to enumerated types as indexers and is in fact of a rather more prosaic nature.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll add more code to explain the problem better as soon as I can

Comment: @David Heffernan:  Could the OP be missing the construct that allows using the enumeration type as a function?  I mean function GetEnum(Value: Integer): TAnEnum;
begin
  Result := TAnEnum(Value);
end;

Comment: You are right, the code in the setter was completly off - got a bit confused myself. I'll get to a pc (online with mobile just now) and update the question, with moee code and fake names so it gets more understandable - atm it's really a mess, sorry about that

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I really hoped it would be possible to somehow get the getters/setters universal. Seems as if I have to stick to the normal way...